# How to set image stored path in docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm new to docker, and I want to config my local docker registry. So I use the command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/opt/scs/v11/docker_registry --restart=always --name registry registry
```

Then,I use the command to push the image to registry:

```
docker pull ubuntu&docker tag ubuntu localhost:5000/batman/ubuntu
docker push localhost:5000/batman/ubuntu
```

I think it will store the image in /opt/scs/v11/docker_registry,But I can't find anything in this file path. I want to know where are my pushing image?
How should I do if I want to store image in special file path?

Comment: which os are you running on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try the environment variable **`STORAGE_PATH`** and map the containers registry path to `/tmp/registry` on your host (or any other available directory).

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000   -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry  -v /tmp/registry:/registry  registry
```

That worked on my centos server:

```
[dude@localhost etc]$ ls -la /tmp/registry/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x.  4 dude dude   38 Jul 16 12:24 .
drwxrwxrwt. 13 root root 4096 Jul 16 12:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root root 4096 Jul 16 12:25 images
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   20 Jul 16 12:24 repositories
[dude@localhost etc]$
```

Taken from [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/registry/)

Comment: Wow! It can work for me, thanks a lot. why does -e  STORAGE_PATH=/tmp/registry, it didn't work? it really need -v to map? May STORAGE_PATH just mean path in container?

Comment: STORAGE_PATH sets the storage path inside the container to /registry. To see that directory outside of the container, the container directory is mounted to the host-directoy /tmp/registry with -v /tmp/registry:/registry

Comment: For current docker versions the environment variable should actually be `REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY`

Answer (score 0):

Based on latest doc at the time https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/ you must map `/var/lib/registry` to your storage.

Like:

```
docker run -d \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v /mnt/registry:/var/lib/registry \
  registry:2
```

##### UPDATE:

https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#/http

```
REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/somewhere
```

This variable overrides the /var/lib/registry value to the /somewhere directory.

Answer (score -1):

From [here](http://www.vmtocloud.com/create-your-own-private-docker-registry-on-vsphere/).

Pull the registry container from docker.io

`docker pull registry`

And then start the registry server

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /docker_repo:/opt/scs/v11/docker_registry registry`

Stop the docker server

`service docker stop`

Start Docker with our local registry (i.e our Docker server IP is 192.168.109.9)

`docker -d –insecure-registry 192.168.109.9:5000 &`

Pull an image from the Docker hub

`docker pull ubuntu`

Tag the image for our local use

`docker tag ubuntu 192.168.109.2:5000/ubuntu`

See your images

`docker images`

Push the image to our local registry

`docker push 192.168.109.9:5000/ubuntu`

Now, we can pull the image from local registry

`docker pull 192.168.109.9:5000/ubuntu`

Comment: I have succeed in pulling image from docker registry. But I want to know where image that I pushed to registry are